# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error but no zombies triggered

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, exc-bad-access

I'm just learning how to use UISCrollView and have written some simple code that loads four customer MenuItem (UIViewControllers) into a UIScrollView.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((scrollView.frame.size.width + menuItemPadding) * menuItemCount, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

//now create and add the menu items

for (int i =1;i <= menuItemCount;i++)
{
    MenuItem *newItem = [[MenuItem alloc] initWithMenuItemDetails:@"Hello"];
    [newItem retain];
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = (frame.size.width + menuItemPadding) * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    newItem.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:newItem.view];
}
```

The line newItem.view.frame = frame is generating an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.  I have tried to track down if newItem is being released too early, which would trigger that error, but I can't see where it would happen, and runnign Insruments with NSZombie enabled doesn't trigger anything.

Any idea why this error is occurring?

Many thanks.

Comment: Might help if you post the code that creates `newItem.view`. Perhaps initWithMenuItemDetails?

Comment: Also, the `[newItem retain];` is unnecessary, `alloc` already returns an "owning" object (meaning you need to release it; with your retain you need to release it twice). Last but not least, you aren't storing or releasing `newItem`, thus leaking it.

Comment: Thanks. I added the retain as a test to check the object was being retained. I'll post the rest of the code now...

Comment: I think newItem is okay, but newItem.view may be wrong.
How do you create the view?

Comment: I'm guessing the bug is in your implementation of MenuItem.  Very likely whatever is in `view` there is the culprit.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks ... the problem is likely with the "view". What is "MenuItem" and how does its view get created? What is the stack trace? If the line above is at the bottom of the stack trace, it is likely that the "view" was not allocated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue here, my init method was simply not doing a

```
return self;
```

hence the object wasn't available. Stupid bug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're doing that work on the main thread

Comment: I found the issue here. My init method was simply not doing.